# How to pass an integer/other variables between threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have four threads running and I want to throw a flag when they're all done.  What I want to do is have an int set to 0.  When a thread finishes it'll add 1 to that int.  I'll have an if statement at the end that'll have the condition that the int has to equal 4.  When that happens a message will show up indicating that all the threads are done.  However, when I try to do this it says ints have to be final or effectively final.  How do I get around this?

Comment: Use a [`CountdownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), decrementing when each thread finishes. Or just `Thread.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to use `Thread.join()`:

```
Thread[] ts = new Thread[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  ts[i] = new Thread(...);
  ts[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < ts.length; ++i) {
  ts[i].join();  // Wait for the i-th thread to die.
}
```

Amongst other alternatives, you can use a `CountdownLatch`, which gives you a little bit more flexibility as to when the thread is considered "finished":

```
Thread[] ts = new Thread[4];
final CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(ts.length);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  ts[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
      // ...
      latch.countDown();
    }
  });
  ts[i].start();
}
latch.await();  // Blocks until all threads have called `countDown()`.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do that. If you want your main thread to be blocked while your other 4 threads are running, you can do

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
```

And this way your main thread will wait for the execution of all the other threads. If you want each thread to increment your flag, you can pass it in their constructors, but you should make the flag `AtomicInteger`

Another way to solve this is to use ThreadPool. You can make a ThreadPool of four threads and assign four `Runnable` tasks to them. Then you can invoke the `.submit(Runnable)` method to the threads. This way the 4 threds would execute the four tasks.

The .submit() method of the ExecutorService (which is the object that operates with the 4 threads) returns a so-called Future object. When invoking future.get() you will know that the thread has finished its task:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

ArrayList<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
tasks.add(new MyThread());
tasks.add(new MyThread());
tasks.add(new MyThread());
tasks.add(new MyThread());

ArrayList<Future> results = new ArrayList<>();

for(Runnable t : tasks){
    results.add(executor.submit(t));
}

int myIntFlag = 0;

for(Future f : results){
    f.get();
     myIntFlag++; 
     System.out.println("Part" + myIntFlag + " of the job is ready")  
}
System.out.println("Whole Job ready")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve the same. Use any of them:

(a) Use Atomic Integer as flag and increase the flag count

(b) use CountdownLatch

(c) you can also tune cyclicbarrier for that (barrier at the end of each thread).

(d) use Thead.join()

~ Java Guru:
Blogger at [Java Interview Questions and Answers](http://javainterviewquestionsexample.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an int counter variable, you could either mark it as volatile or use an AtomicInteger.

`volatile int counter = 0;`

or

`final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();`

Keep in mind that you'll have to loop polling this variable in your main thread until it is 4. If for some reason one of the threads don't get to increment it, your main thread will hang forever.